# Can the HTML meta keyword include spaces in between words?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Can the HTML meta keyword include spaces in between words like so?:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword one, keyword two, keyword three" />
```

(notice the space between "keyword" and the number, that's the space in talking about)

Answer (score 6):

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-meta-element.html) doesn't restrict spaces. Here's the [section](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/common-microsyntaxes.html#set-of-comma-separated-tokens) on comma separated tokens [emphasis mine]:

> A set of comma-separated tokens is a string containing zero or more tokens each separated from the next by a single U+002C COMMA character (,), where tokens consist of any string of zero or more characters, neither beginning nor ending with space characters, nor containing any U+002C COMMA characters (,), and **optionally surrounded by space characters.**

In fact, the [main example on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) includes spaces between keywords.